# What is "Initial WSDL" technically?

Tags: wsdl

Let's suppose there is a link to a web-service, e.g. `http://1.2.3.4:56789/ws_bla_bla_bla/some_service?WSDL`

This address shows [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) document, as I guess this is called `Initial WSDL`.

What is it? Just a list of possibe requests/responces pairs and their xml-structure?

Answer (score 2):

WSDL describes the web service and used to generate client side class which you can used to communicate with service (proxy classes)

couple of generators

http://easywsdl.com/

http://www.wsdl2code.com/

SoapUI is another tool which you can used to test service based on WSDL.